# How to execute the SQL Script through Batch Script Command from SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the .sql file from batch script, but not able to execute.
Script has multiple scripts such as Create Table , Stored Procedure separated by GO statement.

I tried with the below script, however script was not executed.

```
DB Servername : localhost\SQL2017
Authentication : Windows

sqlcmd -E -S localhost\SQL2017\MyDatabase -i C:\SQLScripts\TestScript.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sqlcmd -E -S localhost\SQL2017 -d MyDatabase -i C:\SQLScripts\TestScript.sql
```

You need to use the `-d` parameter to specify the database name. The `-S` parameter should contain only the server name and the instance.